# ‘log’ not meaningful for factors

Tags: r

Tentei rodar um exemplo, mas deu o erro abaixo:

> ## Calcular os log retornos dos ativos
>
> r  <- diff(log(precos))
> Error in Math.factor(precos) : ‘log’ not meaningful for factors
> n  <- length(r)
> Error: object 'r' not found

Alguém sabe como corrigi-lo?

Comment: o seu vetor de preços é do tipo `factor` e não do tipo numérico como é necessário para para usar a função `log`. Meu chute é que vc leu a base e esqueceu de usar o argumento `dec = ","` para especificar que o seu separador de decimais é `,`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Daniel! Transformei os dados para numéricos pela função: precos <- as.numeric(as.character(precos))

Comment: poste por favor a resposta @JPA, ou quem lhe ajudou

Answer (score 1):

```
‘log’ not meaningful for factors
```

significa que você tentou aplicar o logaritmo a um objeto do tipo `fator`.

**Exemplo do problema:**

```
nn <- factor("4233")
log(nn)
Error in Math.factor(nn) : ‘log’ not meaningful for factors
```

**Solução rápida nesse caso:**

```
log(as.numeric(as.character(nn)))
[1] 8.350666
```

**Exemplo de Demais erros:**

```
b <- factor("Caracter")
log(b)
Error in Math.factor(b) : ‘log’ not meaningful for factors
```

Note que se tentar aplicar o `log` a um caracter também não vai rodar:

```
a <- "Caracter"
log(a)
Error in log(a) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function
```

Só é possível aplicar o log a objetos do tipo numérico:

```
c <- 3
log(c)
[1] 1.098612
```